# Negative lookbehind is not matching

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Considering `text = "car price is $2017 and manufactured in 2017 and make is Honda"`, I am trying to write a regex that matches the second 2017 (the manufacturing year). For that I am using negative lookbehind pattern but the string being matched is always the first 2017.

The code I am using is `re.search('(?<!\$)2017', text).group()` and have also used `re.search('(?<!$)2017', text).group()` (without `\`) but no success.

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, the [first regex is matching `2017` that has no `$` in front](https://ideone.com/gz2K33), just what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a negative lookbehind to match 2nd instance of `2017`.

You can use non-greedy quantifier:

```
^.*?2017.*?(2017)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UyG2aL/1)

Second instance is captured in group no. 1

**Code:**

```
>>> str = 'car price is $2017 and manufactured in 2017 and make is Honda'
>>> print re.findall(r'^.*?2017.*?(2017)', str)
['2017']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the `r`, which indicates raw string

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\$)2017', text).group()
'2017'
```

Adding that and your code works.